# What's the difference between readelf and eu-readelf?

Tags: elf

You get eu-readelf from:

> $ sudo apt-get install elfutils

I was just wondering why you would use one over the other ?

Answer (score 14):

On Linux, there are two implementations of `readelf`:

- `readelf` from GNU binutils
- `eu-readelf` from elfutils

The tools from elfutils were written to be smaller, faster, and more featureful than those in binutils.

You can read more about it here ([I](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/readelf/info), [II](http://www.lynxbee.com/what-is-the-difference-between-elfutils-and-binutils/), [III](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-devel-list/2006-May/msg00868.html))